# How to locate html element <input type=number> in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I cannot find input type number element from https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir

Does this mean watir cannot locate such HTML element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watir (both classic and webdriver) support the input of type number as text fields. You can locate it like you would any other text field.

For example, say the html is:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Then you can do the following to check that the element exists (or any other action):

```
browser.text_field(:name => 'quantity').exists?
#=> true
```

If you only want to find elements based on their type attribute being "number", then you will have to use the :css or :xpath locator:

```
browser.element(:css => 'input[type=number]').exists?
#=> true

browser.element(:xpath => '//input[@type="number"]').exists?
#=> true
```

Comment: Thanks, text_field works fine. Wondering where such information is documented.

Comment: Zeljko had started a more comprehensive list in his Watir book, though I do not believe it covered the number input type.